How to connect to Azure - Redis - Passwordless - EntraID from SpringBoot
I have an springboot app that connects to Azure - Redis .
The tutorial following is example
I want to utilize passwordless concept (Entra id) from this - passwordless
The configuration is done. azure configuration
The problem is the passwordless code is using template, whereas the first example does not, and uses Spring Repositories, which is what I prefer.
Model 1 properties that use primary key : (this connects)
spring.data.redis.host=BLAH.redis.cache.windows.net
spring.data.redis.port=6380
spring.data.redis.password=884xn5SOMETHINGCaNPqNfE=
spring.data.redis.ssl.enabled=true

Model 2 properties
spring.data.redis.host=BLAH.redis.cache.windows.net
spring.data.redis.port=6380
spring.data.redis.username=ea37a-some-proper-id7b0ed4
spring.data.redis.ssl.enabled= true
spring.data.redis.azure.passwordless-enabled=true

Error when testing endpoints: (Model2 passwordless)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.implementation.data.redis.lettuce.AzureRedisCredentials]: Factory method 'azureRedisCredentials' threw exception with message: com/azure/identity/extensions/implementation/template/AzureAuthenticationTemplate

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/azure/identity/extensions/implementation/template/AzureAuthenticationTemplate
    at com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.implementation.data.redis.lettuce.AzureRedisCredentials.<init>(AzureRedisCredentials.java:29) ~[spring-cloud-azure-autoconfigure-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0]

What bean is missing and How to fix this?
Note: I had to update properties file in model 1 to fix the issue - azure issue

I did this and it works (1) added dependency (2) azd auth login from intellij terminal. The dependency is  
com.azure.spring
spring-cloud-azure-starter-data-redis-lettuce
. Is the solution correct?

The NoClassDefFoundError might indicate a dependency conflict in the application. Could you check this link to see if it helps troubleshoot the issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/troubleshooting-dependency-version-conflict

The mentioned noclassdef is solved. But I have another follow up issue when I deploy to Azure web app. Managed identity related as I am not using password. I will update when  I get hold of the logs.
